# using gerund in the second sentence

Tags: grammar

In this sentence, is it correct to use the gerund form of the verb (forwarding) in the second sentence (after and)?

> Its main idea is to gather the data from nodes and **forwarding** them
>   to the sink.

Answer (score 1):

The forms of the two verbs should match, so it should be either:

> Its main idea is *to gather* the data from nodes and *forward* them to the
>   sink.

or

> Its main idea is *gathering* the data from nodes and *forwarding* them to
>   the sink.

The first example sounds much better to me, though.